# Load Edit view and Create view in different ViewPages in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have following get method to add a form data and edit form data

Also have table call `AB_Product_vs_Field` in that table I have following columns

- Product_ID
- Field_ID
- Field_Value_EN
- Field_Value_AR

once I pass `Product_ID` and `Field_ID` page number it can find if there any record exist in  `AB_Product_vs_Field`

- if it has a specific record I can load relevant values
- else it doesn't have a record I can load insert as a new record

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Add_Field_Values(int? page, string Product_ID,string FieldID)
  {
      var pager = new PaginationModel.Pager(dummyItems.Count(), page);

      ViewBag.Product_ID = Product_ID;
      ViewBag.FieldID = FieldID;

      //check specific row exist or not in AB_Product_vs_Field table
      if ((db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Any(u => u.Product_ID == Product_ID)) & (db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Any(u => u.Field_ID == FieldID)))
      {
          //edit a product field values
          var product_values = new ProductEdit
          {

              ListProductFields = db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Where((p => p.Field_ID == FieldID)).Where(p => p.Product_ID == Product_ID).ToList(),
              ListProductLables = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.Where(p => p.ProductFieldID == FieldID).ToList(),
              Pager = pager,          

          };

          return View("~/Views/Home/Edit_Field_Values.cshtml", product_values);

      }

      else
      {
          //add new product field values
          var model = new AddNewProduct
          {
              ListProductFields_Add = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.OrderBy(i => i.ProductFieldID).Skip((pager.CurrentPage - 1) * pager.PageSize).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList(),
              Pager = pager                   
          };

          return View(model);

      }
  }
  ```

theses are the the models that relate to above controller

AddNewProduct model class

```
public class AddNewProduct
{
    public string Product_ID { get; set; } }
    public string Field_ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameAr { get; set; }
    public IList<AB_ProductTypeCategoryField> ListProductFields { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Items { get; set; }
    public PaginationModel.Pager Pager { get; set; }


    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }
}
```

this is ProductEdit model class

```
public class ProductEdit
{
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }        
    public string Field_ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameAr { get; set; }

    public IList<AB_Product_vs_Field> ListProductFields { get; set; }
    public IList<AB_ProductTypeCategoryField> ListProductLables { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Items { get; set; }
    public PaginationModel.Pager Pager { get; set; }


    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }
}
```

this is the view of Add New Product

```
@model project_name.Models.AddNewProduct


<h4>Add New Product</h4>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Field_Values", "Home", new { Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">


        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

       <div style="visibility:hidden"> @ViewBag.Product_ID </div>
       <div style="visibility:hidden"> @ViewBag.FieldID </div>


        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldNameEn, Model.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldNameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldID
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN, new { @class = "form-control summernote", @row = 5 })                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldNameAr, Model.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldNameAr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldID) 
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_AR, new { @class = "form-control summernote", @row = 5 })
                </div>
            </div>

             <!-- pagination section -->

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <!-- pager -->
                    @if (Model.Pager.EndPage > 1)
                    {
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            @if (Model.Pager.CurrentPage > 1)
                        {
                                <li>
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Add_Field_Values","Home", new { Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID }, null)">First</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Add_Field_Values","Home", new { page = (Model.Pager.CurrentPage - 1), Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID }, null)">Previous</a>
                                </li>
                            }

                            @for (var page = Model.Pager.StartPage; page <= Model.Pager.EndPage; page++)
                        {
                                <li class="@(page == Model.Pager.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Add_Field_Values","Home", new { page = page, Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID }, null)">@page</a>
                                </li>
                            }

                            @if (Model.Pager.CurrentPage < Model.Pager.TotalPages)
                        {
                                <li>
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Add_Field_Values","Home", new { page = (Model.Pager.CurrentPage + 1), Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID }, null)">Next</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>

                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Add_Field_Values","Home", new { page = (Model.Pager.TotalPages), Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID }, null)">Last</a>
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save Details" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>

            </div>


        }

    </div>  }
     @section scripts{}
```

this is Edit view of product field values

```
@model project_name.Models.ProductEdit

<h4>Add New Product</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Field_Values", "Home", new { Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div style="visibility:hidden"> @ViewBag.Product_ID </div>
        <div style="visibility:hidden"> @ViewBag.FieldID </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductLables[0].ProductFieldNameEn, Model.ListProductLables[0].ProductFieldNameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListProductFields[0].Field_ID)
                @if (Model.ListProductFields[0].Field_ID == "F000014" | Model.ListProductFields[0].Field_ID == "F000015")
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFields[0].Field_Value_EN, new { @class = "form-control summernote", @row = 5 })                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductLables[0].ProductFieldNameAr, Model.ListProductLables[0].ProductFieldNameAr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListProductFields[0].Field_ID)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFields[0].Field_Value_AR, new { @class = "form-control summernote", @row = 5 })

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- pagination section -->

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-10">
                <!-- pager -->
                @if (Model.Pager.EndPage > 1)
                {
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        @if (Model.Pager.CurrentPage > 1)
                        {
                            <li>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Add_Field_Values","Home", new { Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID }, null)">First</a>
                            </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Add_Field_Values","Home", new { page = (Model.Pager.CurrentPage - 1), Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID }, null)">Previous</a>
                                </li>
                        }

                        @for (var page = Model.Pager.StartPage; page <= Model.Pager.EndPage; page++)
                        {
                            <li class="@(page == Model.Pager.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Add_Field_Values","Home", new { page = page, Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID }, null)">@page</a>
                            </li>
                        }

                        @if (Model.Pager.CurrentPage < Model.Pager.TotalPages)
                        {
                            <li>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Add_Field_Values","Home", new { page = (Model.Pager.CurrentPage + 1), Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID }, null)">Next</a>
                            </li>
                                <li>

                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Add_Field_Values","Home", new { page = (Model.Pager.TotalPages), Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID }, null)">Last</a>
                                </li>
                        }
                    </ul>

                }

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save Details" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
    }
    @section scripts{}
```

This add view supposed to add record one by one upto 15 record per one product , those values are save to `AB_Product_vs_Field` for first record its working. but once I click next or number 2 I'm getting following error

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

error occur in this line

> @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListProductFields[0].Field_ID)

in `Add_Field_Values` page

[image]

Comment: Where the error occurring, in edit or add view? if in edit view then your index of list is set to 0, @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListProductFields[0].Field_ID)

Comment: error occur in this line `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListProductFields[0].Field_ID)` in `Add_Field_Values` page which is create page

Comment: ListProductFields list has Field_ID value? Check that in controller or in view.